# Add HTML Tags for all the site pages

Tags: 8, theming

I was searching around but with no clear solution for me!

I would like to add the below HTML code for all my Drupal 8 website pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

How can I do that, is there a contributed module for it ?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you look at MetaTag module? https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/metatag/features-of-metatag-for-drupal-8

Comment: If the MetaTag module doesn't work for you it's possible to do this with a custom theme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. Using metatag module

If you want to do it without custom coding you can try [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module

- enable *MOBILE & UI ADJUSTMENTS* submodule
- go to metatag settings *admin/config/search/metatag*
- edit the *GLOBAL* settings
- under *MOBILE & UI ADJUSTMENTS* fill in *viewport* input box

  [image]

## 2. Using viewport module

There is also a dedicated module called [viewport](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewport) which will allow you to do just that.

## 3. In your custom theme

But can be easily done in your custom theme. Put the following code inside the `THEMENAME_preprocess_html` function in your `THEMENAME.theme`

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $viewport = [
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => [
      'name' => 'viewport',
      'content' => 'width=device-width, user-scalable=no',
    ],
  ];
  $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$viewport, 'viewport'];
}
```

**NOTE:** if `THEMENAME_preprocess_html` function does not exist you can create it and put the code inside.  You can't redeclare it otherwise you will end up with WSOD.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: The metatag module focuses on tags related to the page content, and does not provide a field to set a `viewport` tag.

Comment: It actually does ;-)

Comment: I missed it only looking at the main module :p

Comment: @GiorgosK can you please state the difference between using 'viewport' or the code you provided in my custom theme ?

Comment: Using the preprocess function is a light weight solution compared to using metatag for just this. But if you are already using metatag in your project you can probably use it for viewport as well.

Comment: The provided custom code does not work ! I have created a new file at `/themes/custom/my_custom_theme/my_custom_theme.theme` and added your code (replaced `THEMENAME` by `my_custom_theme`)... clear all caches... But i received a white screen with your code displayed as plain text... any idea ?

Comment: NOTE: I am using a custom theme of the default bartik theme.

Comment: Sounds like you have redeclared `hook_preprocess_html`.  If there is another `my_custom_theme_preprocess_html` inside your `my_custom_theme.theme` the system gets confused with 2 functions with the same name.  Take the code above without the function declaration and put the inside the already existing function.

Comment: There is not another `hook_preprocess_html` even there is only one `.theme` file in my custom theme... I have added  `<?php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute;` to the file and now is working...

Comment: This problem comes from somewhere else, my code snippet does not use any of those Classes.

Comment: mmmm I have only two `.theme` files for the entire website: 1) `.theme` file located at `/web/core/themes/bartik/bartik.theme` which is shipped with the the default theme... and 2) the `.theme` file that I have created in my custom theme.

Answer (score 4):

### A) Theme Template

Probably the simplest way to add a `viewport` metatag is to edit your site theme's `html.html.twig` template.

If you don't yet have a custom theme for your site, and are only using a builtin or contributed theme, you can read the [Drupal 8 Themeing Guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming) to find out more about how the theme system works, and how to [create a sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme) for your site.

### B) [Page Attachments](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843#entire-page)

Another way to add additional metatags is by implementing [hook_page_attachments()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.6.x) in a module.  This is usually done when the value of the metatag may change, but works fine with a constant value as well.

```
function MY_MODULE_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => [
        'name' => 'viewport',
        'content' => 'width=device-width, user-scalable=no',
      ],
    ],
    'meta-viewport',
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, implementing `hook_page_attachments()` in a module is indeed working but I will stick with `.theme` file as it is more simple!